# How to test changes to a cube?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, ssas

There is a process in our company built by a long-departed dev that pulls data from a cube stored in a MS SQL Analysis Server (which I typically access via Management Studio).  The overall process almost never fails and is refreshed several times a day.  However, there appear to be some bugs in the calculations that has been handed to me to investigate and fix.

Unfortunately, I knew nothing about cubes when this was handed to me, was not part of the original development process, and generic web tutorials don't seem to quite apply to whatever I'm looking at.  On the plus side, trial and error has taught me enough that I can ask a few questions.

The bug is definitely in the calculations.  But I obviously don't want to test in Production and I also don't want to make changes without a proper backup (that I know how to revert).

1. Is there a way to export the whole Analysis db to a .SLN file and open it in VS?
2. Should I instead use `Script Cube as`->`Create to`, change the cube name, and execute to make a copy?
3. If I'm later asked to add new dimensions or need to edit the data source, what's the best way to do this?

Any other tips?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Visual Studio project based on an existing cube. This will get everything in a project so you can investigate the calculations, make the necessary changes, deploy to a test environment, and check everything out before deploying to production.  Don't forget to check the project into source control ;-)

[image]